# Problems with large bool array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, primes, boolean

I decided to write a prime number generator as an easy excerise. The code is pretty simple:

```
static void generatePrimes (long min, long max)
    {

        bool[] prime = new bool[max + 1];

        for (long i=2; i<max+1; i++)
            prime [i] = true;

        for (long i=2; i<max+1; i++) {
            if (prime [i]) {
                if (i>=min)
                    Console.WriteLine (i);
                for (long j=i*2; j<max+1; j+=i)
                    prime [j] = false;
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine ();

    }
```

It works just fine with input like 1..10000. However, around max=1000000000 it starts to work EXTREMELY slow; also, mono takes about 1Gb of memory. To me, it seems kinda strange: shouldn't  the bool[1000000000] take 1000000000 bits, not bytes? Maybe I'm making some stupid mistake that I don't see that makes it so uneffective?

Comment: It's worth mentioning that there are better algorithms out there for finding prime numbers.  This won't scale past a certain point no matter how well you take care of all of the little details.  Is your teacher expecting your program to scale to 1 billion/trillion/more values?

Comment: I don't have a teacher — just looking for excersises to gain a bit of xp. I'll google other aglorithms, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope. Contrarily to C++'s `vector<bool>`, in C# an array of `bool` is, well, an array of `bools`.

If you want your values to be packed (8 bits per bool), use a `BitArray` instead.

Comment: I've looked at BitArray documentation, and there is BitArray(Int32) constructor, but no BitArray(Int64) constructor. Is there a way of creating BitArray with more than Int32Max elements?

Comment: You'll have to roll up your own class if you want more elements. A simple solution would be to aggregate several `BitArray`s in your class so that it makes minimal work.

Comment: I guess that's what I'll have to do. Thanks!

Comment: "8 bits per bool"... 8 bools per byte maybe?

Comment: @Dr_Asik Well... more exactly "8 bools as bits per byte".

Answer (score 8):

The smallest unit of information a computer can address is a byte. Thus a `bool` is stored as a byte. You will need special code to put 8 bools in one byte. The [`BitArray`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.bitarray.aspx) class does this for you.

Comment: Bet you it's not one `bool` per `byte`.

Comment: @Blindy: You're on. I'm not on a computer with an IDE, but I want to know what the value of sizeof(bool) is.

Comment: @Blindy: Actually, it's right there on the sizeof page. sizeof(bool) = 1 byte. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eahchzkf(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: The smallest unit of information a computer can "address" is a byte, not "store".

Comment: @Dr_Asik: That is more accurate. Thanks!